# Html.TextAreaFor in asp.net mvc 2 rendering wrong!

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, rendering, textarea

I am developing an asp.net mvc 2 application and am using a *Html.TextAreaFor* to display a textarea where the user can enter a text which is then stored and sent if needed.

The view which displays this functionality is strongly typed (typeof(Message)). The message has a sender, reciver, subject and message body. The code in the view looks like this

`<% using (Html.BeginForm())
       {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset style="height:100%">
        <legend>E-mail</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.To) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.To) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.To) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.From) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.From) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.From) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subject) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Subject) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message) %>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="SaveMail" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <% } %>`

when i open this page in the browser then the submit button is placed over the textarea and i cant get it to render right...anybody help?

Comment: that sounds more like html/css issue to me. do you have a link to the page?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is some CSS problem. Have you tried removing the styles to see if it renders correctly?

Comment: I am pretty new to web programming so I have some trouble with css but after my brother told me to put a <br /> underneath the tetxarea it renders fine now... I'll stick with that for a while because i want to have all ready in time and later i will try to get the css work... thanks for the fast reply

Comment: @Ivan: Tell your brother he should create an account on StackOverflow.

Comment: Just found out that if i write it like this it works fine without <br />
`   <div class="multi-line">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message) %>
        </div>
   `

keypart is class=multi-line